# Delete text from an OpenXML document in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

How do I go about deleting a text string from an OpenXML document? I've tried using `SearchAndReplacer.SearchAndReplace()`, but this can only replace text with other text, rather than remove it completely.

I'm working with an imported DOCX with lots of custom formatting, so the markup is incredibly difficult to work with!

Comment: Just wondering why the replace "your_text" with "" is not an option?

Comment: The method doesn't allow it, it throws an exception.